# MySQL check how many times a word appears inside a table cell

Tags: mysql, text, cpu-word

I want to write a query to select from a table all rows with the word "piggy" in a column called Description.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...?
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, `%` is a wild-card. You don't use wild-cards with the `=` operator but with the `LIKE` operator.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `Description` LIKE "%piggy%"
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: Not only in MySQL: it is the Standard SQL notation (as in ISO/IEC 9075-2:2003 standard).

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where description like '%piggy%'
```

will select and return all rows where the word piggy is part of the value of the column. If you want to count how many rows then:

```
select count(*) from table where description like '%piggy%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where description like '%piggy%'
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned several times you need a `LIKE` query for this. I would only warn that this is going to be terribly slow in case of a `InnoDB` table as it doesn't support fulltext scans. If you want better performance with a `LIKE`, then you should use `MyISAM`.

Anyway, if you want to implement a search engine, better look for existing API's. I don't know what programming language you're using, but if it was Java, I'd recommend [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org).